# For Loop to create Date/Task and convert to calendar

Tags: python

Is it possible to have the results of this loop outputted to a calendar?

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  

turns = 2
dayson = 11
dayoff = 17
total_day = 0

for j in range(0,(turns)):
    for k in range(0,dayson):
        d = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=total_day)
        dt = d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + " Do Task"
        print(dt)
        total_day += 1
    for l in range(0,dayoff):
        d = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=total_day)
        dt = d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + " Don't Do Task"
        print(dt)
        total_day += 1
```

This is a partial output of the results.
I would like to have it look like a calendar with the Do Task or Don't Do Task in the date box.

```
08/12/2018 Do Task
08/13/2018 Do Task
08/14/2018 Do Task
08/15/2018 Do Task
08/16/2018 Do Task
08/17/2018 Do Task
08/18/2018 Do Task
08/19/2018 Do Task
08/20/2018 Do Task
08/21/2018 Do Task
08/22/2018 Do Task
08/23/2018 Don't Do Task
08/24/2018 Don't Do Task
08/25/2018 Don't Do Task
08/26/2018 Don't Do Task
08/27/2018 Don't Do Task
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you break this into smaller pieces. First, print out a calendar without any of the tasks.

Comment: if i could vote this down i would.  JA

Comment: please read [ask] and [help/on-topic] for some tips to improve your question. "Is this possible?" Is ready to answer: yes. But that probably isn't very helpful, so you need to ask a better question.

Comment: Thanks, I would like the output to be html, and have been looking at the HTMLCalendar module.  Ultimately I would like the user to input the different turns and dayson and daysoff intervals.  My problem is getting the loop to work with the modules.  Sorry if I took your first comment wrong.  Looking back at my question, it was a bit vague.